# Google webmaster, I set a preferred domain as www but my subdomain is non www

Tags: subdomain

In Google webmaster, I set a preferred domain as www but my subdomain is non www. Will these cause any negative effect?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We have quite a few questions here already regarding this, like the one marked as a duplicate of. If that doesn't answer your question, then edit your question so it's clear how it differs.

Comment: Technically www is a sub domain. In most cases your domain would exclude the www and the www would be added as a sub domain showing the same contents as the root domain name.  WWW (world wide web) is a relic left over from the days of BBS so one could know the difference. You still want to put a www A record because some people are preprogrammed to type it without even thinking about it. Browsers will also automaticity check for the www when you type the domain into the browser so you can gain a speed boost there.

Comment: The site in question has a redirect to www set in the htaccess file. But there is also a "inventory." subdomain.